# Map network drive without 'net use', and providing credentials in a secure way

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-drive

I would like to map a network drive as a different user. I used the 'net use' command, but i have to provide the password as plain text for it to work.

Is there any method of mapping a network drive where i can pass the pw as a secure string?

I tried to spawn a new process and provide the cedentials to the process itself, but that did not work.

```cs
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Domain = Credentials.DomainNameShort;
proc.StartInfo.UserName = Credentials.UserName;
proc.StartInfo.Password = Credentials.SecurePassword;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"use \\{hostName} /user:{Credentials.DomainNameShort}\{Credentials.UserName} {LoginCredentials.Decrypt(Credentials.EncryptedPassword)} /persistent:no";
```

My expected result was that I would not need to provide a password to net use, if i provided it to the Process, but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to provide credentials in a Windows domain. Both the client and the server know who the user is. All you need to do is ensure the users you want have access to the network share, preferably through group permissions. There are ways to work without passwords in non-domain machines but the actual question becomes "Why are they not in a domain?"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your reply. The problem is, that the current user does not have permissions to view the network drive. Only specail users have the permission, and i have to provide the credentials of the special user, otherwhise the normal windows credentials are used, which have no permission on the network drive.

Comment: Give permissions to the user then. That's the normal, easy, secure, and mandated-by-regulations way of doing things: "special" accounts means there's no traceability or accountability. Never mind that *revoking* access is impossible to do in a timely manner with "special" accounts. On the other hand, if you give permissions to a domain group and add users to that domain group, adding/revoking access is as simple as adding/removing the account from the group. That's something you can do from any domain machine using the management tools

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately it is not my decision to do this. I was only given the task to map the drive without passing the plain text password. Do you know if there is a solution to my problem without granting the normal user permission to the network drive?